# Tableau Calculated Field Logic "If then elseif then else"

Tags: tableau-desktop

Below are the samples of my data. I merged the Epic Data with Initiatives and Project to Domain Data and get the Merged Data, as shown below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GTiM.png)

My goal is to achieve this in Tableau: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3A1Sc.png)

"x" - shows that the Impacted Domain matches one of the Platform Domains, and the number shows the number of rows when it is the case

"!!" - shows that the Impacted Domain does not match any of the Platform domains, and the number shows the number of rows when it is the case.

"??" - needs to show when one of the Platform Domains (e.g., for PORT-1 initiative, domain "D") is not present in the Impacted Domains. The number will always be zero to denote that.

```
IF [Platform Domain - Split 1] = [Impacted Domain]
THEN "x"
ELSEIF [Platform Domain - Split 2] = [Impacted Domain]
THEN "x"
ELSE "!!"
END
```

This calculation works for "x" and "!!" but need help with adding a logic for "??."